# Not able to get data from phpmyadmin in EC2 of AWS

Tags: php, html, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to get data from phpmyadmin which i have installed on EC2 through a php page i made and but no response is coming the error is : The X.X.X.X page isn’t working  X.X.X.X is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 on loginbd.php

login.html

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="http://X.X.X.X/test/logindb.php">
UserName:<input type="text" name="usr"><br><br>
Password:<input type="password" name="pwd"><br><br>
<center><input type="submit" name="sub" value="Login"/></center><br><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

logindb.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="XXXX";
$password="Something i can't tell";
$db_name="sv_db";
$tbl_name="users";
$conn = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$myusername=$_POST['usr'];
$mypassword=$_POST['pwd'];
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="select * from $tbl_name where password='$mypassword' AND       username='$myusername'";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($count == 1)
{
echo ":) :) LOGIN SUCCESS :) :) ";
}
else 
{
echo ":( :( AUTHETICATION FAILURE :( :( ";
}
?>
```

Comment: `phpMyAdmin` is a tool written in PHP to help maintain and manipulate a **MySQL** database.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: What version of PHP did you install into your server?

Comment: So sorry got used to mysql_ :( :( and thank you for helping me out. PHP7 it is.

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql_` database extension has been withdrawn in PHP7.

You will have to use the `mysqli_` or `PDO` database extensions now.